# Element Not Showing on show and immediate async ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to show loading gif and call ajax request (which responds after huge time) and then i hide loading gif.

Below is the code :

```
$('.loading-gif').show();
$ajax({url:'',async:false}).done(function(){...//some operation});
$('.loading-gif').hide();
```

I would like to know why this is happening.
Note :When i check using debug it works but the gif image stops its animating when ajax request is called.
Also what is solution for me to get this resolve.

Comment: It's an ajax call, the code will continue while the call is still running. You should move the hide code into the done function to hide the loading if the call succeeds and also if the call fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JS is single threaded , as you making a ajax request using async flag it halts the thread causing the animation to stop

Also its not a good practise to make sync http calls.

This should solve your problem.

```
$('.loading-gif').show();
$ajax({url:''})
  .done(function(){
    ...//some operation
    $('.loading-gif').hide();
  });
```

Comment: Ok animation stops but the loading-gif also doesn't get displayed... :(

Comment: But for initial when page loads(where the inline css given) the loading is enabled and that time i made a ajax request the animation is running and the loading hide worked

Answer (score 0):

try setting the **async:true** , as it will allow to render UI elements along with ajax call

Answer (score -1):

Jquery `done` function runs only when ajax request completed successfully so call `$('.loading-gif').hide();` in ajax done function.

So ajax code will be look like.

```
$('.loading-gif').show();
$ajax({url:'',async:false})
  .done(function(){
    ...//some operation
    $('.loading-gif').hide();
  });
```

Comment: @Narengs try to replace `done` function with `success` or `complete`. Hope it may work.

Comment: I tried that too it didn't work... and down vote ( i still don't have the privilege to do)